# Dart For Loops, doesn't finish loop

Tags: json, flutter, dart, for-loop

Hey I have this for loop, the for loop execute after making sure that the response is valid and key Restaurants have values,
Index is used for debuging purposes only,
I am not resiving any return value (infinite loading screen)
Also trying

```
for (int i = 0; i <= jsonResponse['Restaurants'].length; i++)
```

but i is never getting to length and finishing the loop
I think the problem might be when adding to the list,

all the values are fetched correctly

```
  int index = 0;
  for (var restaurant in jsonResponse['Restaurants']) {
    var restaurantName = restaurant['Name'];
    if (!hiddenRestaurants.contains(restaurantName)) {
      var restaurantOnline = restaurant['IsOpenNow'];
      if (restaurantOnline) {
        var restaurantImage = restaurant['LogoUrl'];
        var restaurantAddress = restaurant['Address']['FirstLine'] +
            ", " +
            restaurant['Address']['City'];    
        var restaurantDeliveryPrice = restaurant['DeliveryCost'];
        var restaurantDeliveryInt = restaurant['DeliveryCost'];

        var restaurantDeliveryETA =
            "${restaurant['DeliveryEtaMinutes']['RangeLower']} - ${restaurant['DeliveryEtaMinutes']['RangeUpper']}";
        var restaurantETA = restaurant['DeliveryWorkingTimeMinutes'];

        var restaurantTags = [];
        for (var tag in restaurant['Cuisines']) {
          restaurantTags.add(tag['Name']);
        }

        var restaurantRating = (restaurant['RatingStars'] * 2.0) ?? 0.0;

        var loc = restaurant['Id'];
        restaurants.add(Restaurant(
            title: restaurantName,
            image: restaurantImage,
            address: restaurantAddress,
            tags: restaurantTags,
            loc: loc,
            slug: restaurantName.toString().replaceAll(" ", "-"),
            service: DeliveryService.tenbis,
            deliveryPrice: restaurantDeliveryPrice,
            deliveryInt: restaurantDeliveryInt,
            estimateRange: restaurantDeliveryETA,
            online: restaurantOnline,
            eta: restaurantETA,
            country: "",
            score: restaurantRating,
            priceRange: null));
      }
    }
    print(++index);
  }
  return restaurants;
```

Comment: The loop goes on and you get in the console the index printed until stackoverflow error is thrown, or the printing stops at a certain point?

Comment: Please share the error log, if any

Comment: Also, please try to reproduce a complete, hopefully minimal code, that others can execute to see the issue.

Comment: The printing stop at a certain time, around half of the list length, there is no error printing

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= jsonResponse['Restaurants'].length; i++)` is not an idiomatic `for` loop.  It will iterate `length + 1` times.  But really you should prefer a `for`-`in` loop to avoid those kinds of errors (which your actual code seems to be using?).  If you're observing that your  `for`-`in` loop does not iterate over all elements, then either the number of elements isn't what you think it is (print the length first to verify) or something in your loop is throwing an exception that your code is catching and swallowing.

Comment: even with try-catch no error popup, somehow rewrite the class made it work, thanks for the help

Comment: I've had similar problems with object creation from JSON values, especially when dealing with unexpected `null` values or different types. The IDE would throw no error or exception, the program seemed to skip the part and hang there. After debugging it, I discovered that the issue was caused by some value that could be `null` or some value I declared as `int` but was a `bool`, or a custom type.

Answer (score -3):

Why do you use so a strange approach? Please, check this doc
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json
I hope it will help you.
It's more handy firstly to get models from json and doing everything you want with model/models then.

Comment: I am using the same Restaurant class with multiple JSON formats, it is just easier for me to read the code